# Combine knockout models from two different files

Tags: knockout.js

Because of the way a site is built (Joomla), the HTML is pulled together from various locations and JavaScript is added to the head in a, not easily predicted, order.

I have one HTML and js file that include the bindings and a Knockout model to render a generic alert box. Then I have other other files which have their own Knockout models and bindings, from which I'd like to be able to popup the alert box.

I was considering `ko.utils.extend`, and extending each page model with the popup box model, but my actual case is more complex than described and I can't be sure what order the two JavaScript files (page KO model and popup KO model) will appear in the head.

Is there a way to take two KO models and bind both of them, if you don't know the order in which those two models will be placed into the document head?

Comment: Some example code would help this question get answered. It's a little bit vague what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

ko.applyBindings can receive a second parameter that is the dom node will apply the bindings.

So, you can bind two different models in two different dom nodes.

```js
var viewModel1=function (){
}

var viewModel2=function(){
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel1,document.getElementById("div1"));
ko.applyBindings(viewModel2,document.getElementById("div2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div id=div1>
</div>

<div id=div2>
</div>
```

If you apply the bindings a dom node more than once you will get an error.

Comment: @Dom Was useful my answer?